How do I implement HTTPOnly stored JWT Tokens into my React app
I am quite new to React and I tried connecting my backend (Python/ Flask) to my frontend (React). I wanted to use JWT Tokens and save them in the HTTPOnly Cookies, I managed to write some code that creates these cookies and puts them into the HTTPOnly Cookies of the Client but I can't use them, I tried to access an API endpoint but I alwazs get "msg":"Missing Autorsation Header" or "msg":"Missing CSRF Token" as a response. Can anyone help me? Please Dm me if you need more Context.
I tried storing the Token in the localStorrage and adding it to the Header manually, that worked but I don't think that's very secure.

If you are making requests to the same origin as your frontend, don't use JWT at all. It will add 0 security over plain HTTP requests. In this case you can use httpOnly to prevent hostile JS from being able to access it. Every request will get the cookie attached automatically and the browser has a lot of things securing it.

If you are making requests to a different origin, you need to put the token somewhere the the client JS can access it. Cookies or local storage or anything is going to be about equally secure. You can't use httpOnly because then JS can't access the token to be able to forward it to a foreign origin.

Note that you can use either JWT:s or Session-ID's, and you can send them in either a cookie or a header. Most common is to send session id's in cookies, and JWT:s in headers (I assume mousetails comment is based on that) but it's quite often JWT:s are sent in cookies too, and nothing prevents you from sending a session id in a header.
Sending a JWT in a HTTP-Only Cookie is often the safest way (most robust from a security perspective, harder to mess up). This will prevent other javascripts from reading the JWT (and stealing it), and it will ensure that it's not sent to any other origins (that can steal it from there). However this only works in browsers, it only works if your API is located on the same domain (else the browser will not send the cookie) and its only possible if your client code is not depending on the JWT. (Client code should never have any security dependencies on the JWT because client side it can be manipulated, but it can tune the UI according to the access rights the JWT claims that the user to has.)
If you use the JWT in an app (not browser), header is often a better option. (How to store it is described here on SO).
In the Browser inspector, check the cookie header if the JWT is attached at all. And check your backend code whether it expects to receive the JWT in a cookie (and what name of that cookie) or in a header (that is by standards named Authentication.)
